# grammar about Makefile

Tags: macros, makefile, grammar, target, prerequisites

```
WINCONFS = WindowsDebugMinGW WindowsReleaseMinGW

$(WINCONFS) : WINTOOLS=CC=gcc.exe CCC=g++.exe CXX=g++.exe AS=as.exe CND_PLATFORM=Cygwin-Windows

WindowsDebugMinGW : BUILDCONF=WindowsDebugMinGW
WindowsReleaseMinGW : BUILDCONF=WindowsReleaseMinGW
```

Anybody who knows 'a : b=c=d e=f g=h' <=meaning of this grammar ?? 
Codes are in the same line, no tap commands are added.

Comment: Which version of Make? (Try `make -v` if you're not sure.)

Answer (score 1):

It's setting the value of `$(WINTOOLS)` that holds only for those specific targets.

See the documentation about [*Target-specific variable values*](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific).